# Using collections to create random buildings with Blender

Tags: blender

I had the idea of creating a fantasy city, and to avoid having the same house over and over, but not have to manually create hundreds of houses I was thinking on creating collections like "windows", "doors", "roofs", etc, and then create objects with vertex's assigned to specific groups with the same names ("windows" vertex groups, "doors" vertex groups, etc), and then have blender pick for each instance of a house a random window for each of the vertex in the group, same for doors, roofs, etc.

Is there a way of doing this? (couldn't find anything online), or do I need to create a custom addon? If so, any good reference or starting point where something close to this is done?

I've thought of particle systems, or child objects, but couldn't find a way to attach to the vertex a random part of the collection. Also thought of booleans, but it doesn't have an option to attach to specific vertex, nor to use collections. So I'm out of ideas of how to approach this.

What I have in mind:

Create basic shape, and assign vertex to the "windows" vertex group:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir4Cg.png

And then have random objects within the "Windows" collection attached to those vertex, as either a particle or modifier:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlphR.png

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've found a way of doing this.

I'm using 3 particle systems (doors, roofs and windows), each using vertex as emitters, and using vector groups to define where to display one of each the different options.

To avoid the particle emitter to put more than one object per vertex, I created a small script that counts the number of vertex of each vertex group and updates each of the particle system Emission number accordingly.

```
import bpy

o = bpy.data.objects["buildings"]

groups = ["windows", "doors", "roofs"]

for group in groups:
    vid = o.vertex_groups.find(group)
    vectors = [ v for v in o.data.vertices if vid in [ vg.group for vg in v.groups ] ]
    bpy.data.particles[group].count = len(vectors)
```

I've used someone's code from stack overflow for counting the number of vectors in a vector group, but can't find again the link to the specific question, so if you see your code here, please do comment and I'll update my answer with the proper credit.